# How do you write the values of a list of variables to a text file in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to write out the values of a list of variables to a text file using powershell. Whats the best way of doing this?

E.g. I want to output the values of all the below variables to a text file on the c:\temp folder

```
[string] Variable1
[string] Variable2
[string] Variable3
[string] Variable4
```

Comment: Use `Out-File`: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176924.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out:

```
[string] $variable1
[string] $variable2

$variable1 = "one"
$variable2 = "two"

$file = "c:\temp\variables.txt"

$variable1 | Out-File $file -Append
$variable2 | Out-File $file -Append
```

Comment: `$variable1, $variable2 | Out-File ...`